# Error: unexpected symbol in fct_collapse , library is for

Tags: r, forcats

this code i am using , to combine this levels

```
sal$type_employerCap = fct_collapse(sal$type_employer,
fed_loc_state = c(" Federal-gov","  Local-gov ","State-gov "),  
inc_not-inc_ prv = c("Private"," Self-emp-inc","Self-emp-not-inc") , 
? = c("Without-pay","Never-worked","?") ))
```

and my output is :

> Error: unexpected symbol in "sal$type_employerCap =
>   fct_collapse(sal$type_employer,fed_loc_state = c(" Federal-gov"," 
>   Local-gov ","State-gov "),  inc_not-inc_ prv"

i can't understand , what is to be fixed

Comment: I think this is choking on the ?, likely due to that symbol not being [syntactically valid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html) (even though it's fine to use a symbol as a level of a factor).  Try wrapping it in back-ticks, like ` ? `

Comment: @aosmith Or maybe the OP should stop insisting on naming a column `?` if it's a problem. Call that column something else, with a meaningful English name.